# Solve the system $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and $x+y+z = 2+xyz$, where $x,y,z$ are real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and $x+y+z = 2+xyz$, where $x,y,z$ are real numbers.

My idea was to write $$a=-x-y-z$$
$$b=xy+yz+zx$$
$$c=-xyz$$
then $x,y,z$ are solution of $$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$
where $a^2-2b=2$ and $-a=2-c$ so $$2x^3+2ax^2+(a^2-2)x+2a+4=0$$ but could not solve this third degree equation.

Any idea?

Comment: By inspection, one solution is when one of the variables  $=0$,
and the other two $=1$

Comment: Ok, go on... @g.kov

Comment: But $a$ is not a solution to polynomial. @Lee

Comment: Brute force: let $t = x+a/3$ and write the equation in $t$ as $t^3+p(a) t+q(a) = 0$. The discriminant $-4p^3(a)-27q^2(a)$ is non-negative only when $a = -2$. That forces one of the $x, y, z$ to be 0 and all solutions are of the form $(0,1,1)$ or re-arrangements.

Comment: @Aqua  "Complete the cube" using the first two terms - standard way of getting something like $x^3+ax^2+bx+c = 0$ into $t^3+pt + q = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Brute force: let $=+/3$ and write the equation in $$ as $^3+()+()=0$. The discriminant $−4^3()−27^2()$ is non-negative only when $=−2$. That forces one of the $$,$$,$$ to be 0 and all solutions are of the form $(0,1,1)$ or re-arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
x^2+y^2+z^2&=2
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
x+y+z &= 2+xyz
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
a&=-(x+y+z)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
2x^3+2ax^2+(a^2-2)x+2a+4&=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}

The discriminant of \eqref{4} is
\begin{align} 
\Delta&=
18\cdot 2\cdot (2\cdot a)\cdot (a^2-2)\cdot (2\cdot a+4)-4\cdot (2\cdot a)^3\cdot (2\cdot a+4)
\\
&\phantom{=18}+(2\cdot a)^2\cdot (a^2-2)^2-4\cdot 2\cdot (a^2-2)^3-27\cdot 2^2\cdot (2\cdot a+4)^2
\\
&=
-4(a^4-4a^3-16a^2+40a+104)(a+2)^2
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

$\Delta\ge0$, that is, all three roots are real,
is true only for $a=-2$.

Hence, from \eqref{2}, we must have
\begin{align}
xyz&=0
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

so one and only one of the variables must be zero,
and both of the other two must be $1$.